# MMU ( memory management unit )and virtual memory

Tags: cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

I read many articles about this topic but I don't understand how the MMU transfer an address between main memory and virtual memory ( please provide an example )

Comment: Read the intel manuals for system developers, its explained fairly well there.

Comment: Virtual memory doesn't physically exist, you don't transfer addresses anywhere.  CPUs *translate* them from virtual to physical.

Answer (score 3):

The MMU simply translates logical page numbers into physical page frame numbers.

The operating system maintains page tables that define that mapping. The format of the page tables must conform to that specified for the specific processor.

It is just a simple table lookup.

Comment: Well, not always that simple, take x86 for example... :)

Comment: EVERYTHING on the x86 is more complicated than it needs to be. :-(. Longing for the days of 68000 and VAXes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The address Translation is the job of Memory Management Unit(MMU) hardware.
This is the hardware which I expect is self explanatory.

[image]

Also, to understand it in the deep, please refer to [NPTEL Lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF_KP4SMIfM) and this [Quora Link](https://www.quora.com/How-does-memory-management-unit-works)